# Double border using two divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a darkblue box that has an inner white border and an outer blue border. The white-bordered div is situated within a blue-bordered div. But all I get is one big darkblue box.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Practice 2014-4-22-01</title>
<style>
#bannerDiv {
    border: 2 px solid white;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
}
#outerDiv {
    border: 2 px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="bannerDiv">No double border :(</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output: [image]

You can see it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TtwB/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put spaces before units (`px`).

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. Thanks everyone. Man, there's going to be a flood of answers to this one...

Comment: +1 Took me *way* too long to realize this myself. I'm sitting here going back and forth between `inline` and `inline-block` thinking there was some weird trick I didn't know...

Comment: I genuinely felt like crying at my ignorance of the box model. Glad to know I'm just programmatically flatfooted.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use two divs, you can fake a second border with [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and `margin`:

HTML:

```
<div id="bannerDiv">Double border</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#bannerDiv {
    border: 2px solid white;    /* Inner border */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px blue; /* Outer border */
    margin: 2px;                /* Same as outer border width */
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
}
```

Similarly, instead of `box-shadow`, `outline` can be used too:

```
border: 2px solid white;    /* Inner border */
outline: 2px solid blue;    /* Outer border */
margin: 2px;                /* Same as outer border width */
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKw8A/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't put spaces between the number and the measurement:

```
2 px /*Invalid*/
2px /*Valid*/
```

This applies to % as well:

```
2 % /*Invalid*/
2% /*Valid*/
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TtwB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

because you have space between `2 px`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/9TtwB/2/
also, you can do with css, no extra div needed

Answer (score 1):

Remove space

```
#outerDiv {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your css is misspelled should be:

```
border: 2px solid green;
border: 2px solid white;
```

Comment: This answer has already been posted 4 times, man. Why did you post it again?

Comment: sorry you must've posted as I was typing

Comment: Don't feel bad. I'd rather SO have too many people answering questions than too few.